# How to post this div tag?

Tags: php

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label" name="address" for="inputEmail1">Address</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div contenteditable="true">
'.$row['address'].'
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to post the address in.$row['address'].I tried $_post['address'].Its not working any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please make it clear. where your address come from?

Comment: what you want to do? To print `$row['address']` or post it?

Comment: I want to post it in another page for update

Comment: Then assign a name for the div and get it in the posted page using that name

Comment: did you get the answer now from below answer?

Answer (score 2):

replace it with:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<?php echo $row['address']; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print variables inside `<?php ?>` example

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<?php echo $row['address']; ?> 
</div>
```

*Tip:* Alternatively You can also use an short hand method like `<?=row['address'] ?>`

Comment: `short_open_tags` are off by default on most servers, it's not a good suggestion. And although it's ok to omit the trailing `;`, it's not good practice either.